# Haphazard comment moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have noticed the standard for comment moderation has been lacking recently. Entire debates are allowed to develop under some answers while comments that provide specific suggestions on how to better frame a question are deleted with no explanation (save for obviously irrelevant boilerplate like “Please remember that comments are not for answering the question.”). I would urge the moderators to be a little more thoughtful when deleting comments.

Comment: Including the specific question and the content of the comment(s) here might be more helpful, someone, including moderator might follow up why those comments were deleted. Also, moderators should look into the possibility of moving comments into chats.

Comment: I have to agree with this though. Sorry, moderators. Few days back, there was a "factually incorrect question". A fellow countryman of mine made some points. Those were clearly not answers but where OP might look into to get facts corrected. The "boiler plate" after deletion of comments said (says) "post a **real** answer". I was wondering why the extra word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a statement, not an answerable question.

Comment: @bytebusterforLongUsernames There is nothing wrong with this on meta and some huge network-wide precedents (roughly half of the most upvoted “questions” in [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes) are anything but). There is even a “discussion” tag, although I don't really wish a debate as much as a change in behaviour. Deleting any trace of the issue (comments, meta post…) doesn't seem conducive to progress… A post acknowledging the issue could be an appropriate answer for example.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. As is stands, this isn't much more than "Moderation has been rubbish lately", which isn't that useful. Can you maybe link to some threads that you think ought to have been deleted (or to the remnants of threads you think ought **not** to have been deleted? I think the mods can tell us what used to be there). Note that moderator's convenience is an absolutely valid for trashing useful comments as collateral damage during the deletion of a batch of valueless comments; I sure as hell wouldn't have time to sift wheat from chaff, we shouldn't expect them to.

Comment: @DanScally I don't know if that's necessarily helpful but I can give you another example (not the one that motivated this post): I left a comment under https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/57032/does-germanys-union-have-a-significant-eurosceptic-faction to explain my downvote. In fact, the original poster heeded that comment (proof enough that it was legitimate and useful) and I just removed that downvote.

Comment: In the meantime, the comment disappeared while there is a lot of (mostly harmless) chitchat that's still there. What purpose does this serve? There is another super-convenient option for moderators: do nothing.

Comment: @Relaxed If your suggested improvement was included in the answer, it makes sense to delete the comment as "no longer needed" (it served its purpose already and now doesn't provide value anymore). The same is arguably true about the tag discussion. oms comment is more of a pseudo-answer and could likely be deleted as well. My guess is that either your comment was older and mods haven't seen the rest yet, or that your comment was flagged and the others weren't. Mods here likely do rely on flagging to help in moderating.

Comment: @tim As long as my downvote stands, the comment is needed, it would be more useful to notify me. My comments weren't older and my guess is quite different, hence this reminder on meta. This is the only site where this is happening repeatedly to me.

Comment: @Relaxed It's entirely possible that your comment was deleted by normal user flags, not a mod. If a comment gets enough flags relative to upvotes, it is deleted without moderator action. If the user incorporated your suggestion into the question, it's likely that your comment could have gotten ~3+ "No Longer Needed" flags from users pretty quickly

Comment: @divibisan That's certainly possible but, as mentioned in my original message, I also encountered a case where a moderator left an obviously irrelevant message. I have experienced this three or four times during a week and that's the only site where it happens. I don't mean to single out a particular mod or debate a particular occurrence in detail. Mistakes happen, it's the repetition that's annoying and I felt a reminder was in order and the site would be well served with more careful moderation.

Comment: @Relaxed The flag handling interface does not expose the whole comment discussion - only flagged comments. We have to visit the post to see the rest of the discussion, so it's entirely possible that we miss obviously irrelevant comments. If you see them, flag them. We'll get them the next time around.